Do you need to releaseLock on a readable stream when it's hit its end?
When getting a ReadableStreamDefaultReader from a ReadableStream do you need to call releaseLock at the end of the stream, when done equals true, for everything to clean up and not cause a memory leak? Or would letting everything just drop out of scope still allow it to also clean up?

to be honest releaseLock() is created to clean up and prevent memory leak, so the answer is most likely "yes"
